# quarkus websocket request interceptor

Tags: java, websocket, quarkus

I'm trying to migrate existing app (running on Wildfly) to Quarkus. The original code uses servlet filter to intercept websocket session opening requests which works fine on Wildfly. Unfortunately this approach doesn't work with Quarkus. The servlet filter is initialised properly but it doesn't catch the ws requests (regardless the filter is configured using annotation or `web.xml`). `ContainerRequestFilter` implementation doesn't catch the websocket request neither.

What is the mechanism to intercept websocket requests in Quarkus?

Comment: Is the interceptor annotated with `@Provider`?

Comment: yes it is, it works for REST requests but not for ws requests

Comment: Hmm... curious. Maybe asking in the [Quarkus Zulip Chat](https://quarkusio.zulipchat.com/) yields faster results.